# Adding index column to each dataframe in a list R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list with many dataframes, I would like to add a new column in each one of them, this column must contain the position or index of the dataframe in the list.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` :

```
listdf <- list(head(mtcars), head(iris))
result <- Map(cbind, listdf, index = seq_along(listdf))
result

#[[1]]
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb index
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4     1
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4     1
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1     1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1     1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2     1
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1     1

#[[2]]
#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species index
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     2
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     2
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     2
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     2
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     2
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     2
```